# Compare networks, including centrality measures, clustering/community detection results

Tags: classification, clustering, networks, social-network, social-science

Hi my fellow researchers, I am trying to compare two networks based on exactly same group of individuals (179 unique individuals):

- One network is based on these individuals' **meeting** data (two-mode/bipartite) weighted by ***meeting size***.
- The other network is based on their **project assignment** data (two-mode/bipartite) weighted by ***time devoted*** to projects and ***number of people involved*** in each project.

I am required to use R. Since two-mode community detection for large networks is not available in R, I

1. projected both networks to one-mode network (person-to-person). Then I
2. calculated centrality measures using `igraph` & `tnet` packages;
3. did community detection/clustering using `igraph` package (fast greedy, walk strap, Louvain).

Then, I started to compare the results, which is my ultimate goal.

I ranked centrality measures and calculated correlations between corresponding rankings of each measure, for example, correlation between rankings of eigenvalue centrality from project data vs. eigenvalue centrality from meeting data. Key oservations:

- The correlations between ranks of betweenness centrality and eigenvalue centrality are very high (0.93 & 0.83).
- The correlation between ranks of closeness centrality is low (0.38).

For the community detection/clustering results, I used `compare()` function from `igraph` package. I specifically used Variation of Information (vi) and `split.join` methods. Then the `split.join` results tell me that for all three community detection algorithms that I used, it needs to move about 250 nodes to match two community detection results....I only have 179 unique individuals in the network.

Below are **my questions**:

1. How do you think about my strategies to correlate the rankings of centrality measures? Any suggestion? If my strategy does not make sense, please feel free to comment.
2. How do you think about my strategy to compare the clustering/community detection results? Any suggestion? If my strategy does not make sense, please feel free to comment.

The high correlation between rankings of betweenness centrality and eigenvalue centrality tells me that the project network and the meeting network give me similar sets of key players in the network. So if I want to find key players among these people, I can use either the project data or the meeting data.

3. How do you think about my conclusion here? Does it make any sense?

For the fact that the clustering/community detection results from meeting data and project data are so different, what does it indicate? The only thing that I can think of is that the nature of two networks are different. The project data reflects whom you do projects with. For the meeting data, you for sure meet with those whom you do projects with, but you could meet someone else for other reasons... Other than the different nature of project network vs. meeting network causing the difference in the community detection results, I can't think of other reasons.

4. Any comments here? The low correlation between rankings of closeness centrality might also be caused by different nature of project network vs. meeting network?
5. Does it make sense that I got high correlations between rankings of betweenness/eigenvalue centralities, but very different community detection results from project network vs. meeting network?

Thank you in advance for your help here!

Comment: Thank you @Konstantin for editing my question. It is much clearer now!